# How to use Powershell to recursively overwrite every file in a directory and its subdirectories with 0 bytes/nothing?

Tags: powershell, recursion, directory-structure

I have a directory with many subdirectories and all sorts of files (with and without extensions). I want to be able to keep the folder structure as well as the names of all of the files but remove the actual data, keeping the size of the directory down. Maybe it could even only overwrite files over a certain size, but that's not necessary. I thought it might be doable with Powershell, but I'm open to alternatives. Thanks so much for any and all help!

Comment: How many files are we talking here?  The accepted answer works pretty slowly at scale.

Comment: Around 54 GB and I didn't check before but 200,000 files. I have a feeling that's too much.

Comment: You're going to run into a very long script runtime.  Which version of PowerShell do you have installed? `$PSVersionTable` will tell you

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Version 5.1.15063.502. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to retrieve the list of files. Use `Out-File` to write over each.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\example\Path -Recurse -File | 
    ForEach-Object {
        "" | Out-File -Path $_.FullName -NoNewLine -Force
    }
```

Note that `-NoNewLine` is only available in newer versions of PowerShell.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the answer! I've just been tinkering around. Would this also work? `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder -Include * -File -Recurse | foreach { New-Item $_.fullname -type file -force }`

Comment: @MinimumEntropy Absolutely. Many ways to write to a file.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to speed to zero a file, `Clear-Content` was the fastest method with a `12.9` seconds runtime over `10,000` iterations.

- `New-Item -Force` ran at 13.1 seconds.
- `$null | Out-File` ran at 15.2 seconds.
- `'' | Out-File` ran at 18.2 seconds.
- `Set-Content $null` ran at 20.7 seconds.
- `Set-Content ''` ran at 25.8 seconds.
- `$null > file` ran at 16.7 seconds.
- `'' > file` ran at 18.1 seconds.

Functional example:

```
function Write-Zero([string] $Path) { Clear-Content -Path $Path -Force }
```